# Creating Ruby conditional from string

Tags: ruby, string

Bit of an odd question but I want to do something like:

```
a = 6
b = 12

cond = "((a > 5 and b > 10) or a > 50)" #user generated

if cond
  #do something
end
```

How can I parse the string, substitute the variables and run as a conditional.

Comment: Please note that [`&&`/`||` and `and`/`or` in Ruby are **not** the same](http://devblog.avdi.org/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that built-in Ruby way of doing this. You'll have to do some string manipulation and make a method that evaluates this manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have a Ruby string `cond`, you can just do `eval(cond)`. But be aware that people will criticize this for security reasons.

By the way, if you actually do `eval(cond)` to your code, it will return an error because the string `cond` in your example is not a valid Ruby code.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try. Do you mean the missing bracket which I've now added makes it invalid? I realise that a and b won't be valid integers.

Comment: You mean the missing parenthesis. Yes, and it should be okay. In the say it is written above, the evaluated string can recognize the variables `a`, `b`, but once you embed that in a method or something, it will not work because they are local variables. In order to make it work in that situation, you should use the Ruby method `binding`. But that should be another issue.

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
if eval(cond)
 # do something.
end
```